# How to upload default image file in folder PHP

Tags: php, html

How to upload default image file in folder PHP? I am trying to upload selected file or default file in particular folder, but I can't make good.

```
target_file = $target_dir . time()."_abc.jpg";
```

or

```
basename($_FILES["files"]["name"]="abc.jpg";
```

Comment: yes, but how to assign a default file, what i did it is not working. i know upload process but i dont know default file assign.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a file to website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128663/upload-a-file-to-website)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a file to a specific folder using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007074/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload directly by using the filename. Every file has a temporary path where it is stored when it is uploaded. this is referred to by tmp_name. You'll have to upload this tmp_name to the specific directory. Consider below code:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . time()."_abc.jpg";
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
       echo "File Uploaded";
   } else {
       echo "File Not Uploaded";
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear about the scenario in which you are trying to upload default file or selected file. Generally if one selected a file then only the need to upload the file arises otherwise you just keep a default file in folder and show that. If you are concerned about file uploads in php,
you need to follow certain procedures to upload files into folder using any programming language. For the case of PHP first need to check in php.ini whether

`file_uploads = On` if it is On then you can proceed for  file uploading. The form should enable enctype to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Next you can restrict the image format that is to be uploaded, image size etc based on different php functions belong to $_FILES variable.

Please refer this

https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_file_upload.asp